# Backbone Collection overwriting on add

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a jsFiddle showing the issue I'm having when adding a model to a collection, then iterating over the collection. What is happening is that the second model I add to the collection is overwriting the values of the first model I added to the collection.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/4734/

```
Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
    attributes: {},
    constructor: function (event) {
        this.set({
            eventType: event.eventType,
            timestamp: event.timestamp,
            sendingQuota: event.sendingQuota
        });
    }
});
Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    initialize: function (models, options) {}
});

var collection = new Events();

var model1 = new Event({
    eventType: "videoStart",
    sendingQuota: 3,
    timestamp: +new Date()
});
collection.add(model1);

var model2 = new Event({
    eventType: "videoStart1234",
    sendingQuota: 100,
    timestamp: +new Date()
});
collection.add(model2);

collection.each(function (event, key, list) {
    console.log("key" + key);
    console.log(list[key].get("eventType"));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extending `Backbone.Model`, You're overwriting the `constructor`, and overwriting `attributes` with an object that gets shared among instances. So when you call `set` in one instance, it's writing to that shared `attributes` object, which *all* instances read from.

The original `Backbone.Model` constructor function instantiates a new `attributes` object for *each* instance (among other things). So unless there's a reason you're using `constructor`, I'd recommend moving that code to `initialize`, and removing the `attributes` object.